# Why is it not considered creating free energy when you create a vacuum through a siphon?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, potential-energy, vacuum, kinetic-theory

It seems like it doesn't require a lot of work or energy to suck the water in a cup up a straw passed the straw's apex to create a siphon, regardless of how big the cup is or how much water is in it.

My understanding is pressure differentials and gravity play roles in how this works, but it seems like you're creating free energy if you just put all the water in the world in a big pool, and created a siphon for it. Is it the fact that kinetic energy was converted to potential energy when the water was moved into it's container, and now that potential energy is being converted back into kinetic energy as the water flows through the siphon, why energy is conserved?

Does cohesion have anything to do with this as well, or could a theoretical non-cohesive liquid also be siphoned just as easily?

Is this the same as how dominoes that are setup standing, sequentially ordered in progressively bigger sizes are able to knock each other down from just a little push on the smallest domino that ultimately ends up with largest domino at the end falling down (kinetic to potential to kinetic energy conversion)?

Answer (score 1):

It is the gravitational potential energy of the water and of the dominos. When siphoning water, once started, it flows from a higher point to a lower point. The weight of the water in the tube, below the water level, will pull water up over the edge of the cup. In the case of the dominos, when you stand them up you are adding gravitational potential to them. They are balanced on a narrow base, so a small force can tip them past the balance point to let them fall.

Comment: Cool, so it has nothing to do with cohesion? Why doesn't the gravitational potential energy cause the water to automatically siphon out the straw on its own?...why does someone have to start it first?

Comment: @J.D. When the straw has air in it there is no initial force to push water up over the hump. Once started, gravity pulling water down outside the cup will keep pulling water over the hump.